# Can't run the lookup menu right from iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uimenu

I have one question.

The look up menu displayed when text is selected

I wonder if there is no way to run it right away.

Please refer to the screenshot below.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFXc9.png)

No matter how much I look for, I don't know.

I've only found a UIMenuIdentifier called UIMenuLookUp.

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIMenuIdentifier is just constants for identifying an app's standard menus (UIMenu is quite same as AlertController).

You can use [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller) and add your needed action.

Comment: Sorry, I already know what you gave me feedback  
I wanted to know how to run the lookup right away.

Comment: Oh. So you can initial UIReferenceLibraryViewController with the term then present it.

Comment: I would like to thank you additionally
I have been thinking that my question seems to be wrong.
Next time I'll post the question a little more clearly.